# Custom views based on URL in Angular

Tags: html, angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives

I have a requirement wherein I need to load different layouts and skin based on URL in a single angular 2/4 application. How can I achieve that?

For example:

localhost:8080/context/view1 and localhost:8080/context/view2 should show different skin and layout.

Any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: Different skins should be pretty easy by just applying css classes. What do you mean by different layouts? Will you show different components in different places? Or change background or images? Please elaborate

Comment: @hagner - Yes different components like vertical or horizontal menu items, different header and footers, background and images. and if changing css classes is done, where should i configure it? from database or somehwere in cdn or file system? in my index.html, will I be able to read it from different places based on URI? sorry if I sound novice but looking for expert opionons

Answer (score 0):

This is the Angular 2/ Angular 4 router event in which you will get an object on page routing every time either it is parent routing or child routing. It will contain a key **'urlAfterRedirects'** and you can use *ngIf for handling the view.

```
router.events.subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I would handle this is by creating a layout service that is responsible for handling the current skin name, header and footer url and all other skin related information.

**layout.ts**

```
export class Layout {
    skin: string;
    headerUrl: string;
    footerUrl: string;
    //Add all properties you might need
}
```

And here is a skeleton of a service for managing the layout:

**layoutservice.ts**

```
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Router, NavigationStart } from '@angular/router';
import { Layout } from './layout';

@Injectable()
export class LayoutService {
    private _currentSubject = new BehaviorSubject<Layout>(this.getDefault());
    public current = this._currentSubject.asObservable();

    constructor(private router: Router) {
        this.init();
    }

    private init() {
        this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
            if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
                //Navigation occured, check if we should switch layout. 
            }
        });
    }

    private getDefault(): Layout {
        return { skin: 'skin_a', headerUrl: 'http://somewhere.com/header', footerUrl: 'http://somewhere.com/footer' };
    }

    private setLayout(layout: Layout): void {
        this._currentSubject.next(layout);
    }
}
```

So this service will subscribe to any navigation changes and you can apply some logic to see if you should update the current layout. To update the layout, just call setLayout() and all subscribers of the layoutservice will be notified about the change to the layout. 
Now you can just inject this service into any component that would need to know anything about the layout and they can react accordingly.

For example, I would control the skin by applying a css class to one of the top elements. So I would create a css with the default look and then override the skinned items in seperate files:

**default.css**

```
.my-skinned-class {
    color: #000;
    background: #FFF;
}

.my-not-skinned-class {
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

**skin_a.css**

```
.skin_a .my-skinned-class {
    //Override style
}
```

**skin_b.css**

```
.skin_b .my-skinned-class {
    //Override style
}
```

In the AppComponent, inject the layoutservice and then subscribe the current layout:

**app.component.ts**

```
this.layoutservice.current.subscribe(layout => this.layout = layout);
```

And now use the header, footer paths and skin name as you please. The skin here is controlled by binding the name of the skin to the class property of the content placeholder. By doing so, you will be able to update all items within the content placeholder by simply changing the skin name in the layoutservice.

**app.html**

```
<div class="header"><img [src]="layout.headerUrl" />
</div>
<div class="content" [attr.class]="layout.skin">
    <div class="my-skinned-class">This item change skin depending on layout!</div>
    <div class="my-not-skinned-class">This item will not change skin depending on layout!</div>
    <!-- Add content -->
</div>
<div class="header"><img [src]="layout.footerUrl" />
</div>
```